# registrando dados do php em banco SQL server 2008

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Estou com uma dúvida... não sei se estou colocando corretamente o cód, sou iniciante em php e preciso de um help... eu já consegui fazer o form que eu tenho gravar em MySql ... mas agora estou mexendo em um Servidor SQL e não consigo fazer ele gravar os dados... não sei se falta algo ... sei lá... mas eu precisava de um help... vamos lá...

conex.php

```
<?
$con = mssql_connect("000.000.000.00,1111", "user", "senha");
mssql_select_db("BANCO",$con);
?>
```

Essa é a conexão que estou fazendo ... até ai ta tranquilo n da erro ...

esse é o arquivo que grava:

grava.php

```
<?php require_once('Connections/conex.php'); ?>
<?php
$CPF =                       $_POST['CPF'];
...
$TITULO_3 =                  $_POST['TITULO_3'];

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "cpf-form")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO BASE_EY (
  CPF,
  ...
  TITULO_3) VALUES (
  $CPF,
  ...
  $TITULO_3)");

  $insertGoTo = "index.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
?>
```

e esse é o form...

form.php

```
<form action="testego.php" id="camposform" method="post" name="cpf-form" target="_self">
      <div class="medium-8 columns">
        <label for="NOME">Nome<span class="red-red">*</span></label>
        <input name="NOME" id="NOME" value="" type="text" required="required">
      </div>
      <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <label for="SEXO">Sexo<span class="red-red">*</span></label>
        <select name="SEXO" id="SEXO" value="" required="required">
          <option selected="selected" disabled="disable">-- Selecione --</option>
          <option>MASCULINO</option>
          <option>FEMININO</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

...

```
      <div class="medium-2 columns">
        <label for="ANO_GRADUACAO">Ano da Graduação<span class="red-red">*</span></label>
        <input name="ANO_GRADUACAO" id="ANO_GRADUACAO" value="" type="text" required="required">
      </div>
      <div class="div-fix"><input type="submit" class="button medium-4 columns clearfix"></div>
       <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="cpf-form" />
    </form>
```

Não aparece nenhum erro o cód vai direto como se estivesse tudo ok... mas quando vou checar no banco ... NADA... 
Não sei onde estou errando... alguém me da uma luz?? Plz :D

**---------------------------------------------------**
**V-Editado-V**
**---------------------------------------------------**

Eu fiz algumas alteração no cód. conforme as instruções ... mas não deu muito certo... aconteceu a mesma coisa pula direto como se tivesse cadastrado mas n cadastra...
o Cod ficou assim...

Arquivo de conexão

conex.php

```
<?
$con = mssql_connect("000.000.000.00,5033", "user", "senha");
mssql_select_db("banco",$con);
if( $con === false )
      { die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) ); }
?>
```

cadastra.php

```
<?php require_once('Connections/conex.php'); ?>
<?php
$CPF =                       $_POST['CPF'];
...
$TITULO_3 =                  $_POST['TITULO_3']; //crm 02 OBS

  $insertSQL = mssql_execute("INSERT INTO BASE_EY (
  CPF,
  ...
  TITULO_3) VALUES (
  $CPF,
  ...
  $TITULO_3)");

  $insertGoTo = "index.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header("Location: $insertGoTo");
mssql_free_result($insertSQL)
?>
```

mais alguma luz por ai?? rsrs

Comment: No seu código não vi nenhum [mssql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) que é o responsável por executar a consulta. Não tenho certeza se as funções mssql_* funcionam com sql 2008, vc pode usar o [sqlsrv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)([exemplo de conexão sqlsrv](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139%28v=sql.90%29.aspx))   ou [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

Comment: +1 em relação a recomendação do PDO. Segue um artigo explicando o básico de seu uso http://www.diogomatheus.com.br/blog/php/trabalhando-com-pdo-no-php/

Comment: Ok Irei fazer os testes amanhã! Vcs são feras!

Comment: Troque o `mssql_execute()` por: `mssql_query('INSERT ....) or die(mssql_get_last_message());`. Comente essa linha `header("Location: $insertGoTo");` isso vai evitar o redirecionamento assim se tiver algum erro ele é exibido.

Comment: AEEEEE HAHA! Vlw amigo! era isso mesmo! `mssql_query('INSERT ....) or die(mssql_get_last_message());` ele apresentou a mensagem que a tabela "ID" não estava aceitando o campo NULL... ai modifiquei ela para Auto-increment e funfouuu... @perdeu você deveria colocar como a resposta! :D Obrigado a todos ... Agora já estou sabendo um pouco mais de SQL ... nessa parte não irei errar mais rsrs... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu código faltou chamar a função [mssql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php) que é a responsável por executar a consulta. Para resolver Adicione essa linha:

```
mssql_query('INSERT INTO ....') or die(mssql_get_last_message());
```

Quando estiver trabalhando com as funções do banco (mssql_, mysql_, pg_, etc) lembre de chamar a função que exibe o erro no caso [mssql_get_last_message()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-get-last-message.php), em novos projetos de preferência ao [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) ou [sqlsrv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)

Comment: Tks man! Rodando certinho aqui!

Answer (score 1):

Para inserir dados em SQLSRV, é mais chato do que MySQL.

Segue um exemplo de como deve ser usado o SQLSRV:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO [RDO].[dbo].[funcionarios] (usuario, email, senha) VALUES (?,?,?)";

$params = array($nome, $email, $senha);

$stmt = @sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
```